# Get rows that don't exist in a portion of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have data in table1 that looks like so:

```
  DateMonthID    SubscriberID    othercolumns...
     201201           106
     201201           207
     201202           309
     201203           405
     201203           297
```

etc, etc

and table2 like so:

```
  DateMonthID    SubscriberID    Level
       ...           ...          1
       ...           ...          2
       ...           ...          1
       ...           ...          3
       ...           ...          2
```

etc, etc

What I need to do is check which subscribers in the first table do not exist in a range of 3 months in the future in the other table. Does that make sense?

Example: take the subscriberID 106 above in table for the date 201201(January). I need to accrue a count if it does not appear in the other table from 201201-201204(Jan-April).

This is what I have so far but it seems to be returning too many values:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS Total,
    table1.month_key,
    table2.level
FROM
    dbo.table1
INNER JOIN
    dbo.table2 ON (table2.subscriber_id = table1.subscriber_id)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
                WHERE
                (table2.month_key >= table1.month_key AND table2.month_key <= (table1.month_key + 3))
                AND table2.subscriber_id = table1.subscriber_id)
GROUP BY
table1.month_key, table2.level
ORDER BY
table2.level, table1.month_key
```

Any help would be much appreciated

-------------- EDIT --------------
Just to make things clearer because I'm not sure I'm explaining it well. The situation is that in table1 are rows of people who stopped subscribing and the date they stopped subscribing. The thing is this may not be genuine, maybe they just changed subscription or re-subscribed a month later. table 2 is a table full of subscribers for each month. I need to find out who has genuinely unsubscribed by checking if they appear in table 2 between the date table1 says they unsubscribed and then next 3 months. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is `month_key`? Is that the six-digit `DateMonthID`, or something different?

Comment: So, what would your output need to look like?

Comment: The output needs to look like "Total, MonthID, Level". So that the total for each month for each level shows the amount of subscribers for each month in table one that does not exist in the following 3 months in table 2

Comment: So it currently returns values that does exist in the following 3 months in table2?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you cannot add "3" to the month key to get what you want.  Try this instead:

```
FROM (select table1.*,
             (cast(left(month_key, 4) as int)*12+
                                cast(right(month_key, 2) as int)
                               ) as newMonthKey
      from dbo.table1
     ) table1
. . .

where not exists (select 1
                  from (select table2.*,
                               (cast(left(month_key, 4) as int)*12+
                                cast(right(month_key, 2) as int)
                               ) as newMonthKey
                        from table2
                       ) t
                  where (t.newmonthkey >= table1.newmonthkey AND t.newmonthkey <= (table1.newmonthkey + 3))
                        AND t2.subscriber_id = table1.subscriber_id
                       )
```

This changes the monthkey to a month counter since year 0.

Comment: Ah you are correct and you've also helped me notice another underlying problem in that my table2 data only has data for the 2012 year, meaning that October November and especially December subscribers have less to compare to in table 2. So in essence all I should need to do is add a "AND table1.month_key <= 201212-3" to make sure that it cant try and fetch data when all the months in table to to check against aren't available. I know its a bit tacky and your is the correct way if it was big data but I only need to grab this once. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I spoke to soon, The problem is that  as the months go on the totals are getting bigger and bigger, so much so that in the results, by the second month the total of all the totals for the given month are higher than the number of subscribers in table 1 for that month.

Comment: @EvilWeebl . . . Perhaps your outer join needs to join on the monthid as well as the subscriber id.

Comment: I dont have an outer join...do i need an outer join? I'm still pretty new to SQL and although I know which joins are what I'm not very experienced with knowing when to use which.